# What protocol is used by my router to send my dynamic ip to my free DynDNS provider?

Tags: protocols, dyndns

Does every (free) DynDNS provider use its own protocol or are there any standards / specs how it should look like?

Comment: can't believe this was "off topic"

Comment: I nominate this question to be reopened. I just reviewed the scope guidelines and it seems to fall within scope.  It's about a tool commonly used by programmers, and it's still a question with practical value.  How is it off topic?  Just askin...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple HTTP-based protocol, [described here](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/).

UPD: well, I'm not sure about other dyndns providers )

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems like every DDNS provider has its own... Found another one: http://www.changeip.com/clients.asp (see "Dynamic DNS Update Protocol & Specifications" at bottom of site)

Comment: @Sebastian your link is dead